# Angularjs conditional required not working

Tags: angular

I have two inputs of `type="text"` . Atleast one of them should be filled before they can submit the form. The code is as below.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" #formname = "ngForm">

   <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="textToysKeywords" [(ngModel)]="toysKeywords" type="text" name = "tKeywords" required ="'!(clothKeywords.Length)'" #toysKeywordsVar="ngModel"> 
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="textClothKeywords" [(ngModel)]="clothKeywords" type="text" name = "cKeywords" required ="'!(toysKeywordsVar.Length)'" #clothKeywordsVar="ngModel"> 
 </div>

<button class="btn" type="submit" [disabled] = "!formname.valid" (click)="clickMethod()">

</form>
```

This is not working. Unless I enter some value in BOTH the text fields, the button is disabled. How can I correct this?

Comment: use ng change to check if one the input field is valid. Based on it you can enable/disable the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are typing `Length` with uppercase L, so it will return always undefined independent of the field value, and that you are missing the brackets (`[]`) around the required and putting unwanted single quotes.

Change

```
required="'!(clothKeywords.Length)'"
```

To this:

```
[required]="!(clothKeywords.length)"
```

Comment: This throws 'cannot read property 'length' of undefined. Seems, since I am trying to evalulate second textbox.length while the first input field is being rendered, it throws the error! I tried to work-around by changing the condition to [required]="!(textClothKeywords && clothKeywords.length " But its still not working! Any ideas?

Comment: Initialize your ngModel on your controller to an empty string..also show us your controller code.